# spring boot does not read application.properties file when run on command line but works in STS

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am developing a desktop application with spring boot using the STS 4 IDE. Everything works fine inside STS, I have different properties files for different profiles and the main properties file application.properties all inside the resources folder

```
src/main/resources
application.properties
application-dev.properties
application-prod.properties
```

In the **application.properties** I define the environment and the packages to scan to find the entities for the two app databases:

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
wms.basepackage=com.wms
app.basepackage=es.app
```

I run the app using boot dasboard and everything is OK. The problem is when exporting the JAR and I execute it from the command  using the instruction

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev RunableApp4.jar
```

The application fails with the error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [es.app.InterfaceApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'wms.basepackage' in value "${wms.basepackage}"
```

I noticed in the log Differences in steps for run the application from the command line than when run using STS:

STS STEPS (USING BOOT DASHBOARD):

```
es.app.InterfaceApplication      Starting InterfaceApplication on matias-pc with PID 27945 (/home/matias/desarrollo/InterfaceApp/bin/main started by matias in /home/matias/desarrollo/InterfaceApp)
es.app.InterfaceApplication      The following profiles are active: dev
o.s.boot.SpringApplication                 Loading source class es.app.InterfaceApplication
o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener    Activated activeProfiles dev
o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener    Profiles already activated, '[dev]' will not be applied
o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener    Loaded config file 'file:/home/matias/desarrollo/InterfaceApp/bin/main/application.properties' (classpath:/application.properties)
o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener    Loaded config file 'file:/home/matias/desarrollo/InterfaceApp/bin/main/application-dev.properties' (classpath:/application-dev.properties) for profile dev
m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate   Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate   Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 60ms. Found 13 JPA repository interfaces.
m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate   Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate   Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 8ms. Found 4 JPA repository interfaces.
```

The **ConfigFileApplicationListener** enters the scene and loads the main 
 **application.properties**  file and the  **application-dev.properties** environment file. Then the **RepositoryConfigurationDelegate** correctly loads the repositories

COMMAND LINE STEPS:

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev RunableApp4.jar
13:07:49.453 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key 'spring.profiles.active' in PropertySource 'systemProperties' with value of type String
13:07:49.455 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Activating profiles [dev]
13:07:49.455 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Activating profiles [dev]
3:07:49.537 [main] INFO es.app.InterfaceApplication - Starting InterfaceApplication on matias-pc with PID 32173 (/home/matias/Documentos/JARS/RunableApp4.jar started by matias in /home/matias/Documentos/JARS)
13:07:49.537 [main] DEBUG es.app.InterfaceApplication - Running with Spring Boot, Spring
13:07:49.537 [main] INFO es.app.InterfaceApplication - The following profiles are active: dev
13:07:49.538 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Loading source class es.app.InterfaceApplication
13:07:49.580 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@7a1ebcd8
13:07:49.584 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
13:07:49.642 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/home/matias/Documentos/JARS/RunableApp4.jar!/mx/gm3s/configuracion/ConfiguracionDSErp.class]
.
.
Read candidate components
13:07:49.861 [main] WARN org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [es.app.InterfaceApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'wms.basepackage' in value "${wms.basepackage}"
13:07:49.864 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [es.app.InterfaceApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'wms.basepackage' in value "${wms.basepackage}"
```

The **ConfigFileApplicationListener** and **RepositorConfigurationDelegate** do not arrive at the scene, The **AnnotationConfigApplicationContext**  starts to scan components and fails due to being unable to resolve properties values.

I already tried to send  properties file as argument but the result is the same:

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev  -Dspring.config.location=file:/InterfaceApp/src/main/resources/application.properties RunableApp4.jar
```

The main classes are:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(ConfigInterfaceApp.class)
@EnableScheduling
public class InterfaceApp  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(InterfaceApp.class, args);
    }


@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"${wms.basepackage}", "${app.basepackage}"})
public class ConfigInterfaceApp {

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that the `.properties` files are being packaged inside the JAR as well? Try opening it to see if they are there

Comment: Yes, both application.properties and application-dev.properties are in the /RunableApp4  root directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read `application.properties` in your application as follows:

```
ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/path/to/application.properties");
```

**Alternatively,**

```
ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("/application.properties");
```

Answer (score 0):

would you try this one

```
java -jar RunableApp4.jar --spring.config.location=<relative-path-to-configs>/InterfaceApp/src/main/resources/ --spring.profiles.active=dev
```